# Ruby on Rails say/hello throws routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hello everyone im trying to familiarize myself with rails and i created a say controller using aptana studio 3 on windows 7. when i go to 'localhost:3000/say/hello' it gives me a routing error, no routes specified, etc..
so i looked online and found several solutions and i tried to apply them one by one and nothing seems to work right now my routes says

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'say/hello'

  get 'say/goodbye'

  #map.connect 'say/hello', :controller => 'say', :action => 'hello'
  #map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  #map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
  #match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
  #link_to "hello", :controller => "mycontroller", :action => "myaction"
  match '/say/hello' => 'Say#hello', :as => 'say_hello'
  #root :to => 'Say#hello'

  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # root 'welcome#index'

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end 
end
```

one thing i noticed when i go to the demo directory and go to the routes.rb file manually there is nothing but the commented stuff the match command i put is not there. would this be a reason why it is not working ? i saved in aptana shouldnt it reflect that?

Answer (score 0):

You need this in your routes file:

```
get 'say/hello' => "say#hello", as: :say_hello
get 'say/goodbye' => "say#goodbye", as: :say_goodbye
```

And you can take out the match method. The commented out code is just there for reference and will be ignored by the Ruby interpreter. They main reason for the failure in the example code you posted is that the first two get methods don't point to a controller and action.

Here's a link to the Rails routing docs: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: from the tutorial that im following "agile web development with rails 4" they create a demo app and then create a controller with the command "rails generate controller Say hello goodbye" and then all the example showed after that was localhost:3000/say/hello and the web page opened it right up, no modifications to routes.rb mentioned....why is mine funky ?

Comment: You need underscore. e.g. rails g controller say_hello_goodbye